# issue with line break in CSS pseudo-element content string

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my NOOB question, but can somebody explain, why in my CSS popup all space is equal "\n" and throws to next line.
For example i'm need the string :
"Local : 20.08.2014   10:52:36 AM"
but have : 
"Local
:
20.08.2014
10:52:36 
AM"

There is my CSS text, help :

```
.photo4 {
    display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
    position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
}

.photo4:hover:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-title-id);
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 120%; bottom: -250%; /* Положение подсказки */
    z-index: 1; /* Отображаем подсказку поверх других элементов */
    background: #003399;
    font-family: Segoe UI; font-weight: lighter; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    font-size: 13px; /* Размер текста подсказки */
    padding: 5px 10px; /* Поля */
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333; /* Параметры рамки */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

generate text :

```
<script>
var mydateUTC=new Date()
mydateUTC=new Date(mydate.getUTCFullYear(), mydate.getUTCMonth(), mydate.getUTCDate(), mydate.getUTCHours(), mydate.getUTCMinutes(), mydate.getUTCSeconds())
var yearUTC=mydateUTC.getYear()
if (yearUTC < 1000)
yearUTC+=1900
var dayUTC=mydateUTC.getDay()
var monthUTC=mydateUTC.getMonth()
var daymUTC=mydateUTC.getDate()
if (daymUTC<10)
daymUTC="0"+daymUTC
monthUTC=monthUTC+1
if (monthUTC<10)
monthUTC="0"+monthUTC
var hoursUTC=mydateUTC.getHours()
var minutesUTC=mydateUTC.getMinutes()
var secondsUTC=mydateUTC.getSeconds()
if (hoursUTC<=9)
hoursUTC="0"+hoursUTC
if (minutesUTC<=9)
minutesUTC="0"+minutesUTC
if (secondsUTC<=9)
secondsUTC="0"+secondsUTC
var suffixUTC = "AM";
if (hoursUTC >= 12) {
suffixUTC = "PM";
hoursUTC = hoursUTC - 12;
}
if (hoursUTC == 0) {
hoursUTC = 12;
}


var clock = "Local : "+daym+"."+month+"."+year+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+suffix+"


$(".photo4").attr("data-title-id", clock);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that generates this line?

Comment: A live example would be helpful :) The pseudo element may have not enough width to display the text on a single line, try to put an arbitrary width to your :after pseudo-element to check it. (Assuming the text is generated by content: attr(data-title-id); )

Comment: i add script who generate string)
sorryy)

Comment: Doesn't `white-space:nowrap` help?

Comment: yeah, help thanks) but appeared one new problem, with "white-space:nowrap" i can't use "\n"?

Comment: thanks i fixed)) thanks) i'm use white-space:pre